# MySQL - How to convert data_length to actual size?

Tags: mysql, database-administration

I am trying to optimize the database buffer size, but i am finding the

> SHOW TABLE STATUS

rather cryptic. I know that the data length is "165719261184"- how do i convert that into actual megabytes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is in bytes, so divide by 1024^2: 158,042MB

Answer (score 1):

http://www.google.com/search?q=165719261184+bytes+to+MB